# How To Remove The Sudo Pallet Safely

Tags: pallet, sudo

We have the sudo pallet on a running live mainnet. It is almost time to remove it. What is the safest way to remove it in the code? We have made code upgrades before but removing a pallet (especially sudo) makes me nervous. What precisely is the right way to do this safely?

Comment: A way to render the sudo unreachable or provably defunct would also work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this PR.

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/pull/1173

This is how we handle it on our mainnet.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I will study the code changes and follow suit.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no call in the sudo pallet to set the key to `None`.

Undeploying the pallet is therefore the only non-hacky secure solution.
There are other ways, like setting the key to `0x000...` or deleting it by a `System::kill_storage` call, but they are all a bit hacky. Undeploying the pallet is quite easy, just deleting the code in the runtime file should be enough.

PS: Opened [#2165](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/2165) to make this easier.

Comment: That would be a great feature. I hope that goes through!